# How to update data from Serial port in Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm writing a programme that constantly outputs a number, but as soon as the data is read, the programme should call a function and process the received string and write the result into an array. But unfortunately the programme ignores the function for some reason....

Does anyone happen to know what could be wrong?

Here is the *programme code*:

```
const byte buffSize = 60;
char inputBuffer[buffSize];
const char startMarker = '<';
const char endMarker = '>';
byte bytesRecvd = 0;
boolean readInProgress = false;
boolean newDataFromPC = false;
char messageFromPC[buffSize] = {0};
uint32_t tmr1;         // переменная таймера
int time = 0;
int endtest = 0;
int starttest = 0;
//=============

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
}

//=============

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    int *workmas = update();
    starttest = workmas[0];
    time = workmas[1];
    endtest = workmas[2];
  }

  int n = starttest;
  if (millis() - tmr1 >= time && time > 0) {  // ищем разницу
    tmr1 = millis();                   // сброс таймера
    int count = 0;
    while(n < endtest){
        n = n + 1;
        count = count + 1;
        delay(250);
        Serial.print("< ");
        Serial.print(n);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print(count);
        Serial.println(" >");
    }
  }

  Serial.print("<");
  Serial.print(" 1 ");
  Serial.println(">");
  delay(200);
}



int *update(){
  int arrmas[3];

  char x = Serial.read();
  
  if (x == endMarker) {
      
    readInProgress = false;
    newDataFromPC = true;
    inputBuffer[bytesRecvd] = 0;
    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index
  
    strtokIndx = strtok(inputBuffer,",");      // get the first part - the string
    arrmas[0] = atoi(strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    arrmas[1] = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    arrmas[2] = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

  }
  if(readInProgress) {
      inputBuffer[bytesRecvd] = x;
      bytesRecvd ++;
      if (bytesRecvd == buffSize) {
        bytesRecvd = buffSize - 1;
      }
    }

    if (x == startMarker) { 
      bytesRecvd = 0; 
      readInProgress = true;
    }

  return arrmas;

}
```

Comment: I don't see any function that is supposed to be called after data is read.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with this code.

Firstly, it returns arrmas every time, even if the transmission hasn't completed.  So most of the time you get incomplete data. Perhaps update could return a null pointer when the data isn't complete and the caller could check for that.

But the larger issue is that the update function returns a pointer to a non-static local array.  When the update function ends and returns the pointer, the arras array ceases to exist.  The pointer still points to memory, but arrmas isn't guaranteed to still be there and will likely be overwritten by other things.  If you want to return this value then the arrmas array needs to be static.